# errorHandle in multiple, hierarhical RouteBuilders

Tags: apache-camel

I am migration to Camel 3.20.1 from 2.20.1 and am facing some difficulties with my current workflow.
I have three RouteBuilders with routes which are called in hierarchical order like this.

RouteBuilderA

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:dead")
        .maximumRedeliveries(2)
        .redeliveryDelay(1000));

    from("direct:A")
        .to("direct:B");
}
```

RouteBuilderB

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("direct:B")
        .to("direct:C");
}
```

RouteBuilderC

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    errorHandler(noErrorHandler())

    from("direct:C")
       .throwException(new RuntimeException("Something went wrong"))
       .to("direct:end");
}
```

**Current flow:**
As you can see in the code, route in RouteBuilder3 will trigger exception which will be passed to RouteBuilder2. From there it will not be handled, as no error handler is defined for that route, and it will fail with stacktrace...

**Desired flow:**
What I need is to pass that exception to RouteBuilder1 and handle it there where (my global deadLetterChannel) error handler is defined.
One could say, just add `errorHandler(noErrorHandler())` into RouteBuilderB, right. That is clear and it works, BUT I don't want that because...

Because, in that case redelivery will kick in and route message through routes in RouteBuilderB and RouteBuilderC. But, as I got exception in RouteBuilderC, I only want to route message through route where it failed, that is RouteBuilderC.

**Background:**
In old Camel version I somehow managed to make it work by using `includeRoutes(injectedRouteBuilder)`, which is not available anymore. RouteBuilderC bean is injected into RouteBuilderB, which is injected in RouteBuilderA.

**Question:**
Does anybody knows how to solve that? I cannot find a way to make this work. I tried a lot of things, including `getCamelContext().addRoutes(injectedRouteBuilder);`.

*p.s. I am aware of recommendation to use inheritance for RouteBuilders, but in my case this is not an option. I need to pass it to RouteBuilder1 as only that one knows to which error queue, message needs to be send. *